# jquery search autocomplete only works once

Tags: jquery, laravel, autocomplete

I am working with the Laravel framework. For my feed view I have a jquery function to autocomplete my searchinput. After I've send the request to load the same feed with different data, the same function doesn't work anymore. So it basically only works fine the first time but the second time it does nothing. Within my .ready function:

```
$("#keyworduni").keyup(function() {
    var keyword = $("#keyworduni").val();
    $.get( "searchuni", { search: keyword } )
        .done(function( data ) {

            $('#resultsuni').show();

            $('#resultsuni').html('');
            var results = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            $(results).each(function(key, value) {
                $('#resultsuni').append('<div class="itemuni">' + value + '</div>');
            })
            console.log(data);

            $('.itemuni').click(function() {
                var text = $(this).html();
                $('#keyworduni').val(text);
            })

            if($('#keyworduni').val() == ''){
                $('#resultsuni').hide();
            }

        });
});
```

Now I tried to fix this by adding a $(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){});
Wich would be triggered by $.get but this isn't working as well. Any Ideas how to fix it?

EDIT: 
This is the error im getting:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Function.n.parseJSON (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:4)
at Object.<anonymous> (feed.js:176)
at i (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2)
at y (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:4)
```

Comment: When you say "the second time", you mean on the second keyup event? (i.e. when you type your second letter)

Comment: No i mean when i reload the page with different content and want to search again.

Comment: When you reload the content, if the `keyworduni` input is included in that content, you need to re-attach the event listener.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: I added the error I'm getting, maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

change your line

```
$("#keyworduni").keyup(function() {
```

with this:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#keyworduni',function(){
```

#### UPDATE

you are making this a little complicated....try to separate your events "keyup" and "click"

from my experience those event triggers cannot be mixed. If you start with

`$(document).on('keyup', '#keyworduni',function(){`

then you can't have other event triggers inside that function.

If I'm wrong please someone correct me

Comment: this line `$('.itemuni').click(function() {` can't be used...you can't have an event inside another event...

Comment: So that means i should write them separate?

Comment: Yes you should always separate different triggers. Think about them like firing from the gun when you shoot you can't control the bullet anymore. That one is gone. You need another trigger for other action